# DJANGO Strange Behaviour once try to save the files

Tags: python, django

out put is a HTML file which let user upload a CSV file and convert it in excel.
both files appear on the page as user click upload.

strange this happening, sometime user can download the file from the same page if he click on the file or do save as but some time not.

i tried using SYNCDB and rrstart but problem remains as is.

here is views.py

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
        docfile = request.FILES['docfile']       

        path, xfilename = os.path.split(docfile.name)
        xfilename = os.path.splitext(xfilename)[0]
        xnewfilename = 'Modified_%s.xlsx' % xfilename
        newfilename = os.path.join(path, xnewfilename)
        wwdoc = Document(docfile = newfilename)
            wwdoc.save()

        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/koin/Documents/myproject/myproject/myproject/media/documents/'+newfilename)
```

..........SOME DB insert and update........of record in sqlite db

```
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Emp")
        worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet("Manager")
        worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet("Clerk")

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

     documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)l
    )
```

using sqlite3. please guide what is wrong.

list.html

```
{% for document in documents %}
                <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^myapp/', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
    (r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/myapp/list/')), # Just for ease of use.
    (r'', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i figure out that this line in specific stoping user from downloading the file

```
(r'', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),
```

how i can add exception for csv and xlsx files?

Comment: what's the response when they click on the link and the can't download it? 404? 500?

Comment: as mentioned earlier, no response but link show the file path. ""GET /myapp/list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2001"

Comment: this is the issue maker line, (r'', 'myproject.myapp.views.list'),
how i can add exception for csv and xlsx files?